# An example of polytope with exponential number of vertices?

Tags: linear-programming, computational-geometry, polyhedra, polytopes

I am looking for an example of polytope with exponential number of vertices? (Like $2^n$ vertices)
I guess that dual of cyclic polytopes has exponential number of vertices. Are there simpler & more tangible examples? or can someone clarify the approach for dual of cyclic polytopes?

Comment: An $n$-dimensional cube has $2^n$ vertices (but only $2n$ faces).

Comment: I suppose you are looking for a family of polytopes for which the number of vertices is lower bounded by an exponential function in the number of facets? Just having $2^n$ vertices is nothing special: think of a regular $2^n$-gon.